# Check Out Vbproj.vspscc could not be found in your workspace

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to publish a windows form application to a shared drive in Visual Studio 2015.

I am getting the following error:

> Check Out ProjectName.Vbproj.vspscc could not be found in your workspace.

I am using Team Foundation services for source control and cannot see this vspscc file anywhere nor have I deleted it.

Other threads say that opening and closing the ide remakes this file but this is not the case for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please give a sceenshot of how you set in build step? The ProjectName.Vbproj.vspscc file usually won't be added to TFS source control? Why it check out this file, what you set in your build step about this file?

Comment: Not sure I follow as a bit of a novice. Usually I just build the application and got to Build > Publish Application. When i try to publish i get the error above.

Comment: The only difference this time to previous publications that have worked fine is that I'm using source control in team services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by manually adding the vspscc files to tfs and then got that version from source control.

This solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

As of 2017 or 2019, these files cannot be added into source control.

Comment: This is correct - you can't add these file to source control, so I managed to solve the problem by deleting ALL cache files as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608627/files-could-not-be-found-in-workspace.